# How to access a property in a derived class from a base class

Tags: c#, properties

Basically I have a setup to which I need to access a member from a derived class while still having the code reside in the base class, so for example

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>{
     DerivedClass()
    {
        // Set the value to 'test' here
    }
}

public class BaseClass<T> where T : class, new(){
    public int test {get; set;}

    BaseClass()
    {
       // Use the value that DerivedClass set for 'test'
    }
}
```

I apologize if the answer is incredibly obvious

Comment: Are you saying `test` doesn't work?

Comment: How is a base class going to be aware that there's a derived class?

Comment: I actually haven't tried it, I'm using a singleton in my code and I was trying to call it through there, which is using a type to initialize, and I haven't even thought about calling it through just the class. Sorry for such a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access test directly. Example

```
public class Derived : Test
{
    public Derived()
    {
        _test = 5;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int _test;

    public int GetTest()
    {
         return _test;
    }
}

var obj = new Derived();
var test = obj.GetTest(); // returns 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I explained my response to John